# Almacenar respuesta Ajax en propiedad Polymer 2

Tags: javascript, ajax, callback, polymer

Estoy intentando recuperar con **Polymer 2** los datos de un *JSON* que tengo guardado en otro archivo y almacenarlo en una propiedad de tipo *Array*.

El problema es que dentro del *callback* en el *ready* no puedo utilizar el **this** para seleccionar la propiedad y estoy muy perdido sobre como hacerlo.

Los datos se recuperan bien con la petición, llegan bien al *callback* del *ready* siendo `p` un array con todo lo que recupero, pero desde ahí (Donde aparece el comentario con las interrogaciones) no sé seguir.

¿Cómo guardar el array `p` en la propiedad `pokedex` y poder hacer mas tarde un `dom-repeat`?

```js
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/lib/elements/dom-repeat.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/polymer-element.html">


<dom-module id="pokedex-list">
    <template>
        <style>

        </style>
        <div>
            Pokedex
        </div>
    </template>
    <script>
        class PokedexList extends Polymer.Element {
            static get is() { return 'pokedex-list'; }
            static get properties() {
                return {
                    pokedexList: {
                        type: Array,
                        value: function() { return []; }
                    }
                };
            }
            constructor() {
                super();
            }

            ready() {
                this.loadJSON(function (response) {
                    let actualJSON = JSON.parse(response);
                    let p = actualJSON.pokedex;   

                    //???????????            
                });
            }
            
            loadJSON(callback) {
                const requestURL = '/src/json/pokedex.json';

                let xobj = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xobj.overrideMimeType("application/json");
                xobj.open('GET', requestURL, true);
                xobj.onreadystatechange = function () {
                    if (xobj.readyState == 4 && xobj.status == "200") {
                        callback(xobj.responseText);
                    }
                };
                xobj.send(null);
            }
        }
        window.customElements.define(PokedexList.is, PokedexList);

    </script>
</dom-module>
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrías cambiar la función de callback por una función de flecha que heredan el contexto del padre. En ese caso el método ready quedaría así:

```
ready() {
  this.loadJSON( response => {
      let actualJSON = JSON.parse(response);
      this.pokedex = actualJSON.pokedex;   
  });
}
```